# Nested json object in findOne() in express and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
var product = await Product.findOne({$and:[
  { name: req.body.name },
  { extraData: [
    {brand: req.body.extraData.brand} ,
    {quantity: req.body.extraData.quantity},
    {typeOfQuantity: req.body.extraData.typeOfQuantity}]}
  ]});
if (product) res.status(400).send("Product already registered.");
```

What I would like to do is to check if  the given product with these fields already exists in the database so I dont have multiple same object but i have a problem in the nested json object. The code above doesn't work and allows multiple same products to be stored in the array.

The product Scema is:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
},
extraData: {
  type: extraDataSchema,
  required: true
}});

const extraDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  brand: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 10
  },
  typeOfQuantity: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 255
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what these products look like? (btw, if you're using `find` operations to try and enforce consistency, there's always going to be the chance of duplicates from race conditions. If you can instead rely on something like `$addToSet` or a unique index to enforce data consistency, life will be easier)

Comment: @willis is it ok now?